# Picture representation of environments in R?

Tags: r, environment

Please, can you help me to understand the image of the written (how environments work)?:

```
 enclosing <- function() {
 z <- 2
 function(x, y = x) {
x + y + z
  }
 }

 f <- enclosing()
 calling <- function() {
 w <- 5
 f(x = 2 * w)
}
calling()
## [1] 22
```

> The explanation in the book is the following:
>   You start out in the global environment where you define enclosing to be
>   a function. When you call enclosing, you create an evaluation environment
>   in which you store the variable z and then return a function that you store in
>   the global environment as f. Since this function was defined in the evaluation
>   environment of enclosing, this environment is the environment of f.
>   Then you create calling, store that in the global environment, and call
>   it. This creates, once again, an evaluation environment. In this, you store the
>   variable w and then call f. You don’t have f in the evaluation environment, but
>   because the parent of the evaluation environment is the global environment, you
>   can find it. When you call f, you give it the expression 2 * w as parameter x.
>   Inside the call to f, you have another evaluation environment. Its parent is
>   the closure you got from enclosing. Here you need to evaluate f’s body: x + y + z.
>   However, before that, the evaluation environment needs to be set up. Since x
>   and y are formal parameters, they will be stored in the evaluation environment
>   as promises. You provided x as a parameter when you called f, so this promise
>   must be evaluated in the calling environment (the environment inside
>   calling), while y has the default value, so it must be evaluated in the evaluation
>   environment. In this environment, it can see x and y and through the parent
>   environment z. You evaluate x, which is the expression 2 * w in the calling
>   environment, where w is known, and you evaluate y in the local environment,
>   where x is known. So, you can get the value of those two variables and then get z
>   from the enclosing environment.

My try is this:

[Environment representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovTJH.jpg)

Comment: What's your actual question? Or rather what's confusion?

Comment: Don't know why the votes to close this question.  The poster provided specific code, an explanation and an attempt at an answer. The subject states the question clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### environment tree

The hierarchy of environments is shown in the tree below. That is, enclosing and calling are children of the global environment and anonymous (which equals f) is a child of enclosing.

```
Environment hierarchy

.GlobalEnv
    enclosing
        anonymous == f
    calling
```

We can verify these relationships by instrumenting the functions like this:

```
library(pryr)

enclosing <- function() {
  e <- environment(); attr(e, "name") <- "enclosing"
  cat("envir:", environmentName(e), 
      "address:", address(e),
       "parent:", environmentName(parent.env(e)), 
       "parent frame:", environmentName(parent.frame())), "\n")
  z <- 2
  function(x, y = x) {
    e <- environment(); attr(e, "name") <- "anon"
    cat("envir:", environmentName(e), 
        "address:", address(e),
       "parent:", environmentName(parent.env(e)), 
       "parent frame:", environmentName(parent.frame()), "\n")
    x + y + z
  }
 }

 f <- enclosing()
 calling <- function() {
   e <- environment(); attr(e, "name") <- "calling"
   cat("envir:", environmentName(e), 
       "address:", address(e),
       "parent:", environmentName(parent.env(e)), 
       "parent frame:", environmentName(parent.frame()), "\n")

   w <- 5
   f(x = 2 * w)
}
calling()
```

The output of running the above is:

```
envir: enclosing address: 0x11ee1fd8 parent: R_GlobalEnv parent frame: R_GlobalEnv 
envir: calling address: 0x8da2ee0 parent: R_GlobalEnv parent frame: R_GlobalEnv 
envir: anon address: 0x8da0ae8 parent: enclosing parent frame: calling 
[1] 22
```

The above output shows

- the run time environment (or evaluation environment) that is created upon the function being invoked
- its address in memory -- if you run this your addresses would be different
- the parent (or enclosing environment) of the run time environment
- the caller's environment or parent frame

Each environment has a parent and the output shows that the parent of enclosing and calling is the global environment and the parent of anon is enclosing.

In the above each function is invoked once; however, if a function were invoked twice then the run time environment will be different each time.  We would be able to tell this because the address from the instrumented output would be different even though we have named the two instances with the same name.

For example, each time `calling` is invoked a new run time environment is created for that execution instance and the code above would name that run time environment `calling` but we could distinguish the two instances by their different addresses.

On the other hand, the parent of the run time environment is the environment in which the function is defined so it does not change from one invocation to the next.  Thus if we were to invoke `calling` twice two different run time environments are created -- the output from the instrumented code would name both of them `calling` but we could tell them apart because they would have different addresses in the output.  Both these invocations would both have the global environment as their parent since `calling` was defined in the global environment.

Note that `f` is assigned the anonymous function which was defined in `enclosing` so even though the assignment to the name `f` takes place in the global environment its definition (arguments, body, etc.) occurred in `enclosing`.

Note that the run time environment of a function is sometimes called the [evaluation environment](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-lang.html#Evaluation-environment) and the parent environment is sometimes called the [enclosing environment](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-lang.html#Environment-objects).

A useful blog post you might want to review is http://blog.obeautifulcode.com/R/How-R-Searches-And-Finds-Stuff/

#### function calls

The parent frame is the environment of the caller, i.e. the run time environment within the execution instance of the function that called the current function.  The parent frame is not necessarily the same as the parent.  When R searches for objects it searches in the current environment and if not found then it looks in the parent environment and if still not found further up the ancestor tree. R does not search in the parent frame so the parent frame and its call tree are unrelated to the hierarchy of environments.

```
Call tree

  .GlobalEnv
    enclosing
    calling
      anonymous == f
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can better understand the relationship between global, enclosing and evaluation environment with an example. I have slightly modified example from OP.

The value of `z` is not stored at global environment still it persists between calls. The value of `z` is stored in enclosing environment.

```
enclosing <- function(a) {
  z <- a
  function(x, y = x) {
    z <- x + y + z  #This value z will not persist between calls of f.
  }
}

f <- enclosing(2)
calling <- function() {
  w <- 5
  f(x = 2 * w)
}
n <- calling()  #no change in value of z
## [1] 22
n <- calling()
## [1] 22        value of z persisted in enclosing environment between call.
f <- enclosing(4) #value of z is changed to 4 now
n <- calling()
## [1] 24
n <- calling()
## [1] 24       value of z persisted in enclosing environment between call.
```